# Set up Java dxa-example-webapp fails with Nullpointer for missing binary /system/assets

Tags: dxa, dxa-java

### Help requested to set up DXA Sample Java webApp on Tomcat :

Trying to install DXA 1.2 for Java on Tomcat 8+ as-is  distribution from download site.

No changes except config xmls.

Here is `cd_dynamic_conf.xml`, rest of the file is as provided.

```xml
<Host Domain="www.javadxa.com" Port="8080" Protocol="http" path="/com.td.www.dxa"/>
```

#### Exception stacktrace is

> *com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationResolverException: Exception while creating localization: [3] /dxa-example-webapp
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:90) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.getLocalization(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:57) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.interceptor.LocalizationResolverInterceptor.preHandle(LocalizationResolverInterceptor.java:66) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.HandlerExecutionChain.applyPreHandle(HandlerExecutionChain.java:130) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:919) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:856) ~[spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:953) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:844) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:829) [spring-webmvc-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729) [servlet-api.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52) [tomcat-websocket.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AmbientDataServletFilter.java:302) [cd_ambient-7.1.0.jar:na]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:88) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107) [spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar:3.2.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:616) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:521) [catalina.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1096) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:674) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1500) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1456) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.0.30]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_79]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_79]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-util.jar:8.0.30]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
>   Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.localization.LocalizationFactoryException: Exception while reading configuration of localization: [3] /dxa-example-webapp
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.parseJsonFileTree(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:195) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.loadMainConfiguration(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:110) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.createLocalization(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:86) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.TridionLocalizationResolver.createLocalization(TridionLocalizationResolver.java:88) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       ... 38 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: com.sdl.webapp.common.api.content.StaticContentNotFoundException: No binary variant found for: [3] /dxa-example-webapp/system/config/_all.json
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.DefaultProvider.getStaticContentFile(DefaultProvider.java:301) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.tridion.DefaultProvider.getStaticContent(DefaultProvider.java:260) ~[dxa-tridion-provider-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]
>       at com.sdl.webapp.common.impl.localization.LocalizationFactoryImpl.parseJsonFileTree(LocalizationFactoryImpl.java:190) ~[dxa-common-impl-1.2-SNAPSHOT.jar:1.2-SNAPSHOT]*

Comment: The `Localization` exceptions suggest that your cd_dynamic_conf is not properly configured. Did you follow the steps listed here? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20DXA-v2/GUID-2DEBAC0B-C053-4221-B7B9-9966D03A25B1

Comment: can you edit your question and show what is listed in your `cd_dynamic_conf.xml` and confirm that the URL(s) and Publication ID(s) in there are indeed correct?

Comment: @NunoLinhares - Yep have followed all steps as stated in live content.

Comment: @BartKoopman - Thanks for suggestion! Have provided host entry from config file.

Comment: This might sound silly, but are you using that URL and path to access the site? Http://www.javadxa.com:8080/com.td.www.dxa?

Comment: Have you published everything, can you see the binary variants in the broker database, and can you confirm the Publication ID in your `cd_dynamic` is indeed matching with what is in your broker DB. From the stack trace my first thoughts would be a mismatch in that or not everything is published (like for example the Publish Settings Page).

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all suggestions! Here is how I could make it work.

1. Added `dxa-example-webapp` as root application in Tomcat 8 by editing `server.xml` file host element as below

   ```
   <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps" unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

     <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
          prefix="localhost_access_log" suffix=".txt"
          pattern="%h %l %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b" />
     <Context path="/" docBase="dxa-example-webapp">
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
     </Context>
     <Context path="/ROOT" docBase="ROOT">
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
     </Context>
     <Context path="/manager" docBase="manager" privileged="true">
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
     </Context>
     <Context path="/host-manager" docBase="host-manager" privileged="true">
       <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
     </Context>
   </Host>
   ```
2. Modify `etc/host` file on windows to map local host name to a desired domain of DXA application.

   ```
   127.0.0.1 www.javadxa.com
   ```